# The program does not seem to be exiting the loop. Why is that?

Tags: c, loops

This is a simple for loop which the program cannot exit.

```
for(j=4;j<8;j++)
{
    label4:
    b=(rand()%100+1)/1000;
    temp1a[l]=(chrom[i][j]*(0.1-b))+(b*chrom[i+1][j]);
    temp2a[l]=(chrom[i+1][j]*(0.1-b))+(b*chrom[i][j]);
    if(temp1a[l]>0.1&&temp2a[l]>0.1)
    {
        l++;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        goto label4;
    }
}
printf("Initial temp arrays stored\n");
```

The end statement is not being printed and there is no output. Can someone please help me out.

Comment: [goto considered harmful](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf)

Comment: I'll guarantee, with certainty, that the label, continue & goto are all entirely unnecessary and probably actively harmful to the operation of your code. Learn to write half-way decent structured C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pmg points out, you're always assigning a `0` to `b` due to using all integer operands in the division operation.  That's likely contributing to the problem.

Based on your logic, it looks like you don't want to increment `j` unless `l` is also incremented, which only happens when `temp1a[l]` and `temp2a[l]` are above a threshold of `0.1`.

There's a better way to structure the code such that you don't need either the `continue` or `goto` statements:

```
for(j=4;j<8;j++)
{
    do
    {
      b=(rand()%100+1)/1000.0;  // note at least one floating-point operand
      temp1a[l]=(chrom[i][j]*(0.1-b))+(b*chrom[i+1][j]);
      temp2a[l]=(chrom[i+1][j]*(0.1-b))+(b*chrom[i][j]);
    } while (temp1a[l] <= 0.1 || temp2a[l] <= 0.1)
    l++;
}
```

This will compute a new value for `b` and execute the subsequent calculations as long as either result is below the threshold value of `0.1`.  If both are above `0.1`, the inner loop exits and `l` is incremented.  Then the outer loop executes again.

Now, depending on what's in `chrom`, it's still possible that you may hit a situation where the inner loop never exits.  You'll need to do some analysis to see what solutions lead to state where either `temp1a` or `temp2a` never rise above their threshold values, and then add some code to check for those states and not enter the loop.

Answer (score 2):

> `b=(rand()%100+1)/1000;`

The `(rand()%100+1)/1000` part yields `0`.
Net effect:

```
b = 0;
```

Comment: b is float  not int

Comment: I thought so... but the sub-expression is purely `int`. `rand()` returns an integer. `100`, `1`, and `1000` are all integers. The division by `1000` is done with integers.

Comment: Try `b = (rand() % 100 + 1.0) / 1000;`

Comment: To expand on pmg's comment, the result of dividing integer operands gives an integer result - `1/2 == 0`, `3/2 == 1`, `5/2 == 2`, etc.  The result of `rand()%100 + 1` is an integer value between `0` and `100`.  Dividing that by integer `1000` will *always* yield `0`.  It doesn't matter that `b` is a floating-point type, what matters is that the division yields an integer result.  At least one of the operands needs to be floating point to get a floating point result.

Answer (score 0):

The `goto label4` is probably the culprit.

The first line inside the loop is a label. It doesn't do anything, it just says to the compiler 'This place in the code is called label4'. Then, later in the loop the if statement is failing, so the code `goto label4` is executed.

That results in the code jumping back to label4. Something is causing the if statement never to succeed, and so the code eternally jumps back to label4 (the beginning of the loop).